# maintenance screen with nested .htaccess files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

At the top of the root .htaccess file, I have added

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance_503.php [NC]  
#RewriteRule .* maintenance_503.php [L]
```

If uncommented, it redirects the users to a maintenance screen.

However, this doesn't work for subdirectories with their own .htaccess files, and it looks like I cannot use `inherit`, since it appends parent rules *after* child rules. I'd rather not add this rule to every single .htaccess file since I want to have a single point of entry for switching it off and on. Are there any best practices for such a case?

Comment: If you're using apache  2.3.10 or later, you can use `RewriteOptions InheritBefore`!

Comment: that's neat! unfortunately I'm running version 2.2

Comment: The only thing I can think of is removing the `[L]` from any .htaccess files in subdirectories, which should (!!) mean that your rule above would get run last of all, and rewrite anything the previous rules have rewritten.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I just got stuck on this same problem and was about to ask the same question.

Comment: @insaner I ended up putting the maintenance mode on/off switch into the database rather than having it in the .htaccess file. If I could upgrade my apache I would've tried undone's suggestion above.